# In Rails, Turn Off Time Zone Conversion for Specified Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

Pretty simple, I need to disable time zone conversion for specific columns. I will handle any TZ conversion manually, but I need Rails 3 to forego conversion in both *writing* and *reading*, and any AREL functions. But, I don't want to disable the conversion for non-specified attributes.

Ok, I know how to disable it for reading:

```
self.skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes = [:test_timestamp]
```

But this only works for *reading*. When writing the attribute, it still converts to UTC (yes, I tested this in 3.2.8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you note, `skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes` only works for reading, which makes the whole feature pretty useless.

There are two possible solutions:

**1.-** Accept that with times will be written in UTC, and read accordingly:

```
def starts_at # override reader method
  attributes['starts_at'].in_time_zone(whatever_timezone)
end
```

**cons:** overriden method is bypased when using `MyModel.pluck(:starts_at).`

**2.-** Store time values as strings, taking care of writing the values in the right format, and reading them in the desired timezone.

```
def starts_at
 DateTime.strptime(attributes['starts_at'], whatever_format).in_time_zone(whatever_timezone)
end
```

**cons**: one loses the ability to query the database by using date operators (less than, greater than).

Comment: I went with a slightly different form of #2, used integers to store the UTC time. The benefit was that I could construct queries with > or < that you can't with strings (well you could but they would be more complicated to construct).